# Can I sync files from a Surface 2 and a Windows 8 laptop?

Tags: windows, windows-8, sync, windows-8.1, surface-2

I'm thinking of buying a Surface 2 tablet from microsoft, and already having a Windows 8.1 laptop i am familiar with the new Modern UI.

If for example I am playing Jetpack Joyride on my laptop and then I switch to my tablet for whatever reason, can I sync my stats between the two devices?

And if I am using other programs can I sync the files easily between the devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Windows 8, app settings will sync automatically between multiple devices so long as you log into all of them with the same Microsoft account, and you have syncing enabled in the PC Settings app:
[image: screenshot of sync setting]

[Click here for a full-resolution version of the screenshot [1920x1080]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1zeh.png)

If you want to sync other arbitrary files, you can also do this easily via your Skydrive cloud storage, also included with the Microsoft account. Windows 8.1 has deep integration with Skydrive so it just appears as another local storage location available to you.